# Entity Manager, creating query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have such a two classes:

```
public class Average {
long id;
String name;
double average;
public Average(long id , String name , double payment)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.payment = payment;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return id + "\t" + name + " " + payment;
}
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Payment{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
long    id;
Student student;
Subject subject;
double  payment;

public Payment()
{
}
```

and I want to perform query on this class with java, but it is not working correctly. What can be wrong. Bellow I posted my query from another class where I call it:

```
public List<Object> getPayment()
{
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("Select NEW Average( g.subject.id , g.subject.name , AVG(g.payment) ) from Payment g GROUP BY g.subject.id, gge.subject.name");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Please be patient with me, this is my first post!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include information about what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is wrong, because query does not show anything. There are also no errors...

Comment: Have you turned on Hibernate debug logging?  Whenever something's not working in the database (as opposed to in your Java code), that's the thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Average` is not an entity (you should annotate it with `@Entity` - like the one you did for `Payment`) so you cannot perform `entityManager.createQuery()`. 
Also you should specify table `@Table(name = "XXX")` after `@Entity` and before class name.

Query should be something like:

`Select  g.subject.id , g.subject.name , AVG(g.payment)  from Average a, Payment g GROUP BY g.subject.id, g.subject.name`

**-- UPDATE**

If `Average` is a Bean class used for projection then do the following:

```
 Object[] payments = (Object[]) entityManager.createQuery("Select g.subject.id,
 g.subject.name, AVG(g.payment) from Payment g
 GROUP BY g.subject.id, g.subject.name").getSingleResult();
```

then iterative through the objects of `payments`:

```
for (Object object : payments) {
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

if the result is just one row then put `getSingleResult` otherwise you need a `List` of the objects and iterate through the list:

```
List<Object[]> payments = (List<Object[]>) entityManager.createQuery("Select g.subject.id,
     g.subject.name, AVG(g.payment) from Payment g
     GROUP BY g.subject.id, g.subject.name").getResultList();
```

then iterative through the objects of `payments`:

```
if (payments != null){        
    for (Object[] object : payments) {
        System.out.println(object[0] + " " + object[1] + " " + object[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I need this part:

`from Average a`?

Comment: Base on the query you provided I thought you need it. If don't need it then remove it.

Comment: The `Average` object is just used for projection, so why should he add the `@Entity` annotation? The query you proposed does not make sense.

Comment: That's a wrong way for projection though. You cannot perform `entityManager.createQuery()` on non entities. He should do the `createQuery()` on `Payment` first and then get the results back (List of array of objects) and then map them to the Bean Class (Average). I thought Average is an entity, and that's why I proposed to annotate it with `@Entity`.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the `gge` instead of `g` in `GROUP BY g.subject.id, gge.subject.name`?